# Blog pages not using the custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, blog

I am working on Mangento (1.9) website and the site uses a custom theme which is applied throughout all the pages. I didn't build the theme, the previous team who worked built the theme and the blog pages also used that theme and it worked fine until a few days ago.

The pages on the website uses the custom theme, though the blog is using a default theme (looks like web 2.0) that Magento provides (not sure as I am new with Magento, but it seems like it)

I did make some changes to the various XML files to add a few blocks but didn't change anything else in files like `pages.xml`.

The configuration of the blog seems to be alright on the admin panel

[image]

It took me a lot of effort itself to find how to edit the layout, and I've been searching about editing the configurations for which theme Blog should use but no results till now.

Any idea why it might be happening? I am very new to Magento so I am not sure where to look at.

Comment: Your issue is juste to change the layout ? if you change the Page Layout config nothing happen ? the blog use well your custom theme you haven't problem with this right ?

Comment: Changing the page layout in the config. does some changes on the actual blog page, but the theme that is being used isn't the one on the main website (which is a custom theme package we are using throughout the site).

Comment: So you want to apply this custom theme used in the website in the blog right ?

Comment: Yup. A few days earlier it did apply the custom theme, but after I made some changes to `pages.xml`, `layout.xml` (I don't even remember which other files, thanks to the big set of files) I later found out the Blog didn't apply the custom theme like it did before.

Comment: Look my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Logically in Magento when you set a theme in `admin >design`, Magento apply it for all pages, even if you dont put the file in the theme files, Magento go to get it from default then base as **Magento fallback system**.

Now if you you have set some config or updates by mistakes, the only way that I know is to set the theme manually in xml, you can also set it in controller.

**Solution:**

**XML:**

Try to put the code bellow in : `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<your_layout_handle>// try this <blog_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTheme">
            <theme>your-theme</theme>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

you can also set it in controller:

```
protected function _construct(){
   parent::_construct();
   Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
        ->setPackageName('packagename')
        ->setTheme('your-theme');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I do have a good feeling this will help me. Only problem is there isn't any `layout.xml` in that folder. There is however `page.xml` which I think substitutes `layout.xml` file here. Is that true?

Comment: To do it properly, you do it in `local.xml` as my path, now if you tel me that the page.xml do a job for you put it on it ;)